# Android setText add numbers

Tags: android

I need do something like this:

```
name.setText("Text" + number1 "+" + number2);
```

Why it does not work in Android?

Comment: Post the relevant code, along with the Logcat

Comment: what is that you want to doo add those numbers what? what o/p are u expecting

Comment: You are missing + sign right before "+"

Answer (score 1):

Change to this `name.setText(" Text " + number1 + " + " + number2);`

Sum of two numbers : `name.setText(" Text " + number1 + " + " + number2 + " Sum :" + (number1+number2));`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display it as text you have to write

```
name.setText("Text " + number1 + "+" + number2);
```

if you want to sum up the 2 numbers, you have to write

```
name.setText("Text " + (number1+number2));
```